# Determine the least prime $p$ for which $2^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod {p^2}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Determine the least prime $p$ for which $2^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod {p^{2}}$ .

Comment: The second-least is 3511, so you have only to check finitely many $p$. (Incidentally, I haven't found a third one yet with brute-force up to 200000000).

Comment: How would I check this using Mathematica?

Comment: I am trying to write a C program. But there is some error. Can you please check it for me http://paste.ubuntu.com/5724647/

Comment: Such primes are known as [Wieferich primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime). After the first 2, there are no others up to $10^{17}$. There is an ongoing search at PrimeGrid; see http://www.primegrid.com/forum_thread.php?id=3008&nowrap=true#45945 and http://prpnet.mine.nu:13000/

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150264/prove-21092-equiv-1-pmod-10932-and-31092-not-equiv-1-pmod-1093?lq=1

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zmPZN.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Using Mathematica, I found out a prime such that $2^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod {p^{2}}$.

My code is as follows:

primetable = 
Table[Mod[2^(Prime[i] - 1), (Prime[i])^2], {i, 1, 3000, 1}]

Position[primetable, 1] 
The position where 1 occurs is at the 183th prime, which is 1093.

For proof, I will compute $2^{1093-1} \equiv 1 \pmod {1093^{2}}$ through successive squaring.  $2^{1092} \equiv (16)(606814)(917050) \equiv 1\pmod {1194649}$

In sum, the least prime would be 1093.
For clarification, all calculations were made using a calculator.