# Prove $2^{1092}\equiv 1 \pmod {1093^2}$, and $3^{1092} \not \equiv 1 \pmod {1093^2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I did try to factorise 1092 and it is equal to $2^2*3*7*13$ and I really don't know what I can do with this. Do I need to calculate all the powers?

Comment: The first one is related to [Wieferich primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime), see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367358/determine-the-least-prime-p-for-which-2p-1-equiv-1-pmod-p2

Comment: You don't need to calculate all the powers. With exponentiation by squaring, you only need to compute ten times a square modulo $1093^2$, and then two modular multiplications, since $1092 = 1024 + 64 + 4 = 2^{10} + 2^6 + 2^2$. That's still not easily doable in one's head, but with pen and paper, it's not much work.

Comment: As 1093 is prime, Fermat's Little Theorem seems the natural route to go

Comment: Using idea of @DanielFischer, we can show that $3^{1092} \not \equiv 1 \pmod {1093^2}$ as follows:

$3^{4} \equiv 81 \pmod {1093^2}$.

$3^{64} \equiv 59025 \pmod {1093^2}$.

$3^{1024} \equiv 483115 \pmod {1093^2}$.

Multiplying first and second relation gives -

$3^{68} \equiv 4781025 \equiv 2429 \pmod {1093^2}$.

Now, multiplying it by the third relation, we have -

$3^{1092} \equiv 1173486335 \equiv 341017 \pmod {1093^2}$.

Which certainly shows that
$3^{1092} \not \equiv 1 \pmod {1093^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the demonstration for $2^{1092}\equiv 1 \pmod {1093^2}$

[image]